# Rerouting all traffics from one interface to another

Tags: routing, iptables, nat, forwarding, network-interface

I'm using linux. I have a device connected to the ethernet interface on my motherboard (enp0s31f6) and my PC has a wireless card (wlp5s0) which is connected to the router . The device is sending DHCP discover requests to the enp0s31f6 interface. I want to reroute all traffic from the ethernet interface to my router.

From what I know, I have to make the ethernet port on my motherboard act as a default gateway for the device and activate IP forwarding.
After that I need to make sure my PC knows what to do with incomming packets for the device, so I should use NAT

I've tried this but it doesn't seem to work, the packets still get trapped on the ethernet interface:

```
#enabling ip forwarding in the kernel
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

#flushing old rules and deleting chains
iptables -F
iptables -X

#masquarading and forwarding
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING --out-interface enp0s31f6 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD --in-interface wlp5s0 -j ACCEPT
```

It seems like a really simple problem, but I cannot find a solution for it. Does anyone know how to solve this?